# Methods to pass an arraylist to another class to check availability and its expired dates

Tags: java, encoding

I have an `Arraylist` and I want to pass it to another class to check availability and its expired dates. What are the methods?

```
public Boolean Checkup (Product[]x, String code ) { 


   if (Product.contains(true)) {
   \\ why it is error    
       System.out.println("Product is availible");
   } 
   else 
   {
       System.out.println("Product is not availible");
   }

}
```

Comment: Please put more effort into the asking of your question. What errors are you seeing? What is the code supposed to be doing? Explain, expand,... Also why are you passing a boolean into the `contains(...)` method?

Comment: I've created an Array list of products in another class, and I want to check if the product is available or not in the CheckUp class and i don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing that you should make a bit more clear is what data structure you use to store products. I assume it is ArrayList since you mention it and you use the 'contains' method. But in your checkUp method you use an array of products as an input. Here examples of both:

```
Product[] products = new Product[5]; // This is an example of array of products

List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>(); // This is an example of an ArrayList of type products
```

Now I will go on assuming you intent to use ArrayList.

Since I see you are passing a code, I think you intent to find the product with the specified code. So for a class that could look like this:

```
public class Product {
    private String code;
    private String otherValue;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getOtherValue() {
        return otherValue;
    }

    public void setOtherValue(String otherValue) {
        this.otherValue = otherValue;
    }

}
```

You then would need a method to find out if your ArrayList of products contains a product with this code. It could like this:

```
public Optional<Product> tryGetProductWithCode(List<Product> productList, String targetCode) {
    for(Product product: productList) {
        if(product.getCode().equals(targetCode)){
            return Optional.of(product);
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

And then your checkup method would be:

```
public boolean checkup(List<Product> productList, String targetCode) {
    Optional<Product> potentialProduct = tryGetProductWithCode(productList, targetCode);
    if(potentialProduct.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("Product is present");
        return true;
    }else {
        System.out.println("Product not found");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now I saw you used the contains method, and even though I do not think that this is what you need, let me give a bit more info about it.

In the contains method you should pass an instance of class Product. Then calling the contains method, it will try to find if the product you provided as input is indeed member of the ArrayList. It would look like this:

```
productList.contains(someProduct);
```

It will return true or false. It checks if it is "contained" using the equals method of the Product class, so be sure to override it. Here is a helpful [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/). Also your IDE such as IntelliJ or Eclipse can do this for you and allows you to select which attributes to use in the check.

But my guess is that the above solution is what you need for your case. Last thing, check this at some point for [java naming conventions.](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)